# How to match the end of a line but not a paragraph with a regex in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to join all lines in a paragraph, but not join one paragraph with the next.

In my text file, the paragraph is not defined by blank lines in between them, but with a period at the end of the line. There could be white spaces after the period but it still defines the end of the paragraph.

So, I wanted to do a macro that jumps to the next end of line, not stopping on those lines that have a period at the end.

I used this regex:

```
[^\.\s][\s]*$
```

Meaning: find any character that is not a period nor a whitespace, optionally followed by whitespaces to the end of the line.

I would then apply the `J` command to join the matched line with the next one, and then repeat.

It works fine on [RegexPal](https://regexpal.com), but in Vim it stops at lines that have a period and two spaces.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That one finds the end of every paragraph.  I wanted to find every end of line but those, to apply th J command.  Maybe I coud use your search to apply an alternative to J that joins all selected lines instead of this one with the next...  Using visual mode, I guess?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the regex in a macro in conjunction with the `J` command, how about using a regex substitution to remove linebreaks? This seems to work for me:

```
:%s/[^\.]\s*\zs$\n\(^\s*$\n\)*/ /
```

Explanation:

- `[^\.]\s*\zs$\n` -- lines not ending with a period; start the replacement before the linebreak.
- `\(^\s*$\n\)*` -- include any further lines containing only whitespace

This regex is then replaced with a space.

Answer (score 2):

If the cursor is located at the first line of a paragraph,
one can join its lines with

```
:,/\.\s*$/j
```

To do the same for all paragraphs in a buffer, use the command

```
:g/^/,/\.\s*$/j
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you part way there:  use *shime*'s regexp (`\.\s*$`) to identify lines you want to join, then use `:v//j!` to join each such line to the next line.

Then repeat the `:v//j!` command until done.  (Define a macro to do it:  `:map v :v//j!<cr>` then just hit `v` repeatedly.)

A better solution, if you're on a *NIX-like machine is:

```
awk '/\.\s*$/ { printf("%s\n", $0);} { printf("%s", $0); } END { printf("\n"); }' <your_file >your_other_file
```